# Question related to functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I am interested in studying functional analysis and I am wondering what sort of practical applications the field has and what, if any, career paths might require functional analysis. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE! Hilbert spaces are a vital part of functional analysis which in turn are the basis of quantum mechanics and quantum computing.

Comment: Wouldn't finite dimensional Hilbert spaces be enough for quantum computing, since you only have a finite number of qbits? Then you could argue whether functional analysis is necessary for this case.

Comment: Right. At least you have unitary transformations.